# How to make my C# console program not close instantly?

Tags: c#, cmd, console, exe

Alright, so I have a problem. My code prints out text giving options to type any of three things. If you type one of them, it writes a line. But for whatever reason it just closes instantly (in visual studio I would use Ctrl + f5) after printing out the text, but because I'm trying to launch from .exe I can't do that. How do I make the window stay open and not close after printing the result out.

My Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This console application was written by Graham Long.
    /// 
    /// This is a series of basic programming items that I am using to help myself learn c#
    /// </summary>
    class Program
    {
        //Below is a function
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //All of the code starts here. Some call this an 'entry point'.

            String myString = "Hello world! My name is Graham and I am the developer of this application.";
            Console.WriteLine(myString);
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            Console.WriteLine("Type 'q' for an explanation of some British slang.");
            Console.WriteLine("Type 'w' for some meta text.");
            Console.WriteLine("Type 'e' for the same compliment printed twice.");

            ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo = Console.ReadKey();
            if(keyInfo.KeyChar == 'q')
            {
                Console.WriteLine("'Chav' is British slang for 'Council House And Violent', council house meaning a house on rent from the council (They're cheap, which means they're usually associated with poorness) and violent meaning easily angered and vicious.");
            }
            else if(keyInfo.KeyChar == 'w')
            {
                printSomeTextToScreen();
            }
            else if(keyInfo.KeyChar == 'e')
            {
                printNiceTextToScreenTwice();
            }

            //Console.WriteLine("Did you type {0}?", keyInfo.KeyChar.ToString());

        }
        static void printSomeTextToScreen()
        {
            //Using a separate function from 'Main' ('Main' is the main function).
            String someText = "This is some text being printed from a different function.";
            Console.WriteLine(someText);
        }
        static void printNiceTextToScreenTwice()
        {
            //Using another separate function from 'Main', this function includes a 'for' loop which is a piece of code that runs until a condition is met.
            String niceText = "You have a lovely fore arm.";
            for (uint counter = 0; counter < 2; counter++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(niceText);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry for bad formatting in advance (just in case).

Comment: `Console.ReadLine` ??

Comment: Now is your chance to improve your participation rate and show your thanks by clicking the checkmark next to the answer to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't tell the application to do anything it will just finish. For instance, you can add this line at the end of your `Main()` method:

```
Console.ReadKey();
```

This tells the program to wait until another key is hit.

Answer (score 0):

Use while loop, based on some key(s) entered you can exit the loop.

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //All of the code starts here. Some call this an 'entry point'.           
        do
        {
            String myString = "Hello world! My name is Graham and I am the developer of this application.";
            Console.WriteLine(myString);
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            Console.WriteLine("Type 'q' for an explanation of some British slang.");
            Console.WriteLine("Type 'w' for some meta text.");
            Console.WriteLine("Type 'e' for the same compliment printed twice.");
            Console.WriteLine("Type 's' to close.");

            ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo = Console.ReadKey();
            if (keyInfo.KeyChar == 'q')
            {
                Console.WriteLine("'Chav' is British slang for 'Council House And Violent', council house meaning a house on rent from the council (They're cheap, which means they're usually associated with poorness) and violent meaning easily angered and vicious.");
            }
            else if (keyInfo.KeyChar == 'w')
            {
                printSomeTextToScreen();
            }
            else if (keyInfo.KeyChar == 'e')
            {
                printNiceTextToScreenTwice();
            }
            else if (keyInfo.KeyChar == 's')
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        while (true);
    }
```